# Include child key only if the same key is also declared in the parent while serialization

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I know its a design fallacy, but I have to deal with it. Same field is declared in both a parent class and its child class. However while serialization, I expect to include only the child's if it is set.

```
class Parent {

    private int field;
}

class Child extends Parent {

    private int field;
}

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Child child = new Child();

        System.out.println(gson.toJson(child));
    }
}
```

But the above code is throwing error indicating that the child has duplicate field. I have tried with the exclusion strategy but it doesn't give access to the field value to check if it is set. How can I resolve this issue ? 
**P.S.** Gson is optional. I can go with any other library if it gives me the required flexibility. So library suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either:

1) Register a custom `JsonSerializer`:

```
private static class ChildSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Child> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Child arg0, Type arg1, JsonSerializationContext arg2) {
        JsonObject r = new JsonObject();
        r.add("field", new JsonPrimitive(arg0.getField()));
        return r;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = 
        new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(
            Child.class, 
            new ChildSerializer()
        ).create();

    Child child = new Child();

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(child));
}
```

This will serialize the object correctly.

2) Use the `@SerializedName` Gson annotation in order to serialize the child field with a different name:

`@SerializedName("childField")
private int field;`

of course this implies that you have to change the logic after deserialization in order to take into account the correct field of the deserialized object.
`

3) Change the field to `protected`? Don't know if it's viable but then when you will just have either the parent or the child value, without duplicates.